# Can I make an excel template that will save as CSV automatically?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I want to make an excel template `xltx` that will automatically save the resulting workbook as a `.csv`.

Open template -> blank workbook (and template data) -> Save ->
[image] CSV format already set.

I do not mean the option to set the default save format for myself; I'd like this to be specifically for the template so if I give it to someone else it will still default to saving as `.csv`.

Comment: I don't believe that function can be stored in a template. Using a macro may work, but macros are largely blocked for shared files these days, and for good reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since you want automation only for the Excel Templates in that case only VBA Macro can do this.*

- Press **Alt+F11** to open the VBA editor.
- Insert a new module, by clicking **Insert** then **Module**.
- **Copy** & **Paste** this Macro.

---

Sub SaveAsCSV()

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "Output.csv", xlCSV

End Sub

---

**N.B.**

- The file names *Output.csv* is editable.
- **Save** & **Close** the VBA editor.
- Whenever you want to save your Excel template as a CSV file, you can
  use **Alt+F8** to run this Macro.
- Ensure that **Macros in** option must be **ALL Open Workbooks**.

Comment: Thank you. Marked as accepted since it does seem to be the only way.

Comment: @MikeDannyboy  ,,, glad to hear from you that this VBA code is working as expected ☺